# Is there something similar to array[1:] in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Working with an array of strings and I want to recursively call a method with the parameter being the array from index 1 to the end. In python, it looks something like array[1:], and i've been searching for something similar in java but nothing yet, thanks!

Comment: It might be over kill, but [`System.copyArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) would do the trick (oh and your making a copy of the array as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You must pass around the start index and (possibly) the end index. This would look like:

```
public static void doThing(int[] array, int start){
    //do something here to array[start]
    doThing(array, start+1);
}
```

Comment: Blah, that was so handy in Python! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about you move to `List`:

```
Integer[] array = ...;
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
list.subList(1, list.length());
```

If your array has to be 'primitive' `int`, then you can use [Trove's TIntArrayList](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TIntArrayList.html#wrap%28int%5B%5D%29).